# Can WinMerge be used as a plain text diff tool, without needing to compare existing files?

Tags: text-editors, comparison, winmerge

I want to use WinMerge as a plain text diff tool, without needing to compare existing files.

That is, I'd like to just click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, paste two plain texts onto both sides, hit <kbd>f4</kbd> and find differences.  I tried it, but it results in "No difference" message.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, but you can do just about the same using two dummy files for the
comparison.

Any time that you change anything in the two files, WinMerge will re-compare immediately their text.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; see @jose-gaspar's answer below!

Answer (score 9):

How it worked for me, using WinMerge:
File > New > Text
results in two panes "Untitled left" and "Untitled right".
Then pasted text into the panes and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, which made de comparison.
After the comparison, closed all with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused that it didn't work, didn't know about F5.

Comment: This is should have been accepted as the correct and most informative answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. As several others said, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then **<kbd>F5</kbd>**. If it says *No difference* then the contents are identical

[image: Identical files]

See the untitled panes?

**Why on earth do you use <kbd>F4</kbd>???** <kbd>F5</kbd> has always been the shortcut to refresh in any compliant apps. The refresh feature has existed in WinMerge long before 2008, probably since the first version

[image: Different text files]

There are even other related features if you check the [change log](https://winmerge.org/docs/changelog.php?lang=en)

> #### Clipboard Compare
>
> - New Feature: Clipboard Compare (PR #1147)
>
>   - Click File → Open Clipboard menu item to compare the two most recent contents of the clipboard history.
> - You can also compare by pressing Ctrl+V when the child MDI window is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

As you ask your question, no.  WinMerge (I have it and use it) is a file comparison tool and needs to load in both files to compare. You do not have to compare but that is the point of the tool.

The message you got (it results in "No difference" ) means the files are identical.  I see this as well.

So WinMerge is working properly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, exactly the way Jose describes it. Ctrl-N, Paste the two texts, hit F5, voilà. I do that a lot because our code is not stored in files.

Comment: The question asks a yes/no question. I answer that. I also answer the implicit question how to do it, step by step. How is that not an answer?

Comment: If the complaint is referring to the deleted part; I understand. But I just want to help, and I can't because the karma doesn't let me do anything besides writing answers.